# Is there an easier way of doing this array assignment in python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a more readable way of doing the array assignment (the for loop part).

```
spike_train = np.zeros((2,2000)) # Array to be filled

spikes = np.random.randint(low=0, high = spike_train.shape[1]-1, size = (2,100)) # Indexes to fill

for i in range(spikes.shape[0]):  # I feel that this part could be more readable
    spike_train[i, spikes[i,:]] = 1

#I was thinking something along these lines:  spike_train[spikes] = 1, but I know this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to broadcast the first dimension (instead of `repeat` as @Valdi_Bo and @Andre do - which constructs a big intermdiate array):

```
spike_train = np.zeros((2,2000)) # Array to be filled

spikes = np.random.randint(low=0, high = spike_train.shape[1]-1, size = (2,100)) # Indexes to fill

spike_train[np.arange(spikes.shape[0])[:, None], spikes] = 1
```

You can also use `np.put_along_axis` in this case:

```
np.put_along_axis(spike_train, spikes, values = 1, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this taught me something new.

np.arange(spikes.shape[0])[:, None]

This is a pretty clever way to get an array into that shape!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As @DanielF pointed out the approach I describe here is not best practice. I'll leave it here for reference, but see @DanielF's asnwer for a more optimal solution.

---

Another appoach is to get the  "`x`, `y` coordinates" of the spikes and set those to 1.

With `x` refering to the row (i.e. `0` or `1`) and `y` referring to the index.

Here's how you could implement this:

```
import numpy as np

spike_train = np.zeros((2,2000)) # Array to be filled
n_spikes_per_row = 100
x = np.repeat([0,1], n_spikes_per_row)
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high = spike_train.shape[1]-1, size = 2 * n_spikes_per_row) # Indexes to fill

spike_train[x, y] = 1
```

Maybe a bit redundant to tell, but `x` and `y` are flat arrays holding the randomly selected coordinates like so:

```
x = [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
y = [13, 5,  7,  4,  9, 14,  1,  1, 17,  4]
```

As a final comment: since you're selecting random integers you might get the same value in `y` multiple times, this leads to fewer 'spikes' in the final array. Maybe you already knew or it does not matter fot your implementation but I wanted to have mentioned it just in case. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  All of the answers provided on this thread offered great solutions, but I think this is the easiest one to explain to beginning students.

Comment: @Potatoconomy Please don't teach beginning students not to use broadcasting.  We spend so much time trying to beat that out of people in our answers here.  Using `repeat` isn't easily extensible to higher dimensions, is slow and wasteful of memory, and ignores one of the fundamental benefits of `numpy`.

Comment: Also, even if you don't want to broadcast, using `np.put_along_axis` (see my edit) is better practice as well

Comment: @DanielF, Thanks for the comment, I didn't know that! I'll edit to my answer.

Comment: @Andre Sorry for putting you on blast.  I normally wouldn't do that but if they're going to be teaching it to others I'd rather make sure best practices are followed.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to write the indicated elements without an explicit loop is:

```
spike_train[(np.repeat(np.arange(spikes.shape[0]), spikes.shape[1]), spikes.flatten())] = 1
```

But the execution time is even longer.

Another option is to change the last instruction to:

```
spike_train[i, spikes[i]] = 1
```

(no need to explicitely pass the ":" for the second dimension).
This time execution is a bit faster than your original code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the readability part, but if your intention is really to eliminate the `for` loop, you could try this (my real answer is in the **penultimate line** of the code - the rest of the code is just setting up the demo data or just printing stuff):

```
import numpy as np

TRAIN_LEN = 10                       # Should be 2000 in reality

# Initialize with sequential values, just to demonstrate that this answer
# works correctly, and updates with ONES in the right places
spike_train = np.arange(2*TRAIN_LEN).reshape (2,TRAIN_LEN)

print (spike_train)
SPIKES_LEN = 5                        # Should be 100 in reality
spikes = np.random.randint(low=0, high = spike_train.shape[1]-1, size = (2,SPIKES_LEN)) # Indexes to fill
print (spikes)

# Here's where we actually do the update
spike_train[np.arange(spikes.shape[0], dtype=np.intp).reshape(-1,1), spikes] = 1
print(spike_train)
```

**This prints:**

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]
[[4 8 0 6 0]
 [8 8 4 3 3]]
```

**and, after the update:**

```
[[ 1  1  2  3  1  5  1  7  1  9]
 [10 11 12  1  1 15 16 17  1 19]]
```

Notice that the **2x10** array of sequential numbers is now updated, to have **1's** in all the right places.